# Trying to use Opencore Macrecovery to download dmg of Ventura and getting error

Tags: python, windows, macos, dmg, opencore

I installed python on windows 11 to use Opencore to download a dmg of Ventura OS. When I try to download it using opencore I get the error: "No Installed Python found!" I'm a total noob so apologies if this doesn't make any sense.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeTqf.png)

I tried to add python to path but doesn't make a difference

Here is the youtube tutorial I'm trying to follow: [text](https://youtu.be/s_zlanxCWeM?t=231)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.